RBF Interpolation for increasing dataset
I have a dataset with 20 features and 65 samples. The models performed poorly, so I used scipy.rbf for interpolation and added 300 additional samples to the dataset. The models' performance significantly improved, and almost all models achieved an R2 of 99% on the training and testing sets. After performing cross-validation, the results were still around 99%. Is there a way to determine if my new dataset is significant, and the R2 of 99% is not due to random chance or overfitting?
